# Can't get rid of cursor when hiding TextArea in Qt Quick Controls

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

The issue seems so trivial that I almost believe it's a bug in Qt itself:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        color: "white"
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        radius: 5
        width: 640/2
        height: 480/2

        TextArea {
            id: txtMemo
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 5
            textColor: "black"
            wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
            readOnly: false
        }
    }

    Button {
        x: 0
        y: 480/2
        width: 640/2
        height: 480/2

        onClicked: {
            //Qt.inputMethod.hide()
            txtMemo.visible = false
        }
    }
}
```

You need to run this on an Android device to see the bug:

[image]

1. Type something in to the text area so the cursor and virtual keyboard appears.
2. When you click the button, the cursor & keyboard stay on screen. No idea why, perhaps a feature.

Anyways, that's not the main issue. When I uncomment `Qt.inputMethod.hide()` and trying to reproduce, an interesting thing happens:

- if the keyboard is visible, both the cursor and keyboard disappear - awesome, exactly what I want
- however if the keyboard isn't visible (closed by the arrow on the bottom during typing) *and* the cursor is, the cursor won't disappear at all:
  [image]

(apologies for the picture quality)

So how do I get rid of the cursor? Tested on Qt 5.9.6 on Android (seems unrelated on Android version, happens on the latest version as well).